# Unix sed command sort and compare

Tags: unix, sed

Lets say i have a file name demo which contains an essay. how can i sort a  the file alphabetically and then compare it the result with a file name demo2 using sed or anything else.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a one-liner:

```
diff <(sort demo1) <(sort demo2)
```

Answer (score 0):

First, sort both files, then `diff` them:

```
sort demo1 > demo1sorted
sort demo2 > demo2sorted
diff demo1sorted demo2sorted
```

Answer (score 0):

Probably best to use `diff`:

- http://www.gnu.org/software/diffutils/manual/diffutils.html

for this purpose. Something like this:

```
sort demo > demo_sorted
sort demo2 > demo2_sorted
diff demo_sorted demo2_sorted
```

You can read starting from here

- http://www.gnu.org/software/diffutils/manual/diffutils.html#Sample-diff-Input

about the different versions of the output you can produce.